# Group Audience field in Group Content does not show any values other than None

Tags: 7, organic-groups, entities

I am a OG newbie and followed examples and created a new content type called "Team" and a new content type called "Item" and associated it as a Group Content Type for "Team".

I created a new "Team" called "Team 1" and when I try to create a new "Item", in the Group Audience field I only see "None" as an option.  When I change the Group Audience field setting in "Item" to "Select List" instead of "OG Reference", I see the "Team 1" as part of the list.

The problem is that this workaround is not sufficient because I want to get the "Create Item" link in the Team's page using Entity Reference Prepopulate module.  However, not having it as "OG Reference" causes issues with using entity reference pre-populate field setting for the Group Audience field (getting an AJAX 500 error when I select entity reference pre-populate checkbox).

Any idea what I am doing wrong?  I am using OG 7.x-2.7, Entity Reference 7.x-1.1 and Entity Reference Prepopulate 7.x-1.5  ﻿

Answer (score 0):

Making sure the Group is published solved the issue for me.